# R packages for Distributed processing

Tags: r, distributed-computing

I am currently have a R query that can do the parallel processing within a loop using foreach. But it is done using a single server with 32 cores. Because of my data size, I am trying to find the r packages that can distribute the computing to different window servers and can work with foreach for paralleling.

Really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkR is the answer. From ["Announcing SparkR: R on Apache Spark"](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/09/announcing-sparkr-r-on-spark.html):

SparkR, an R package initially developed at the AMPLab, provides an R frontend to Apache Spark and using Spark’s distributed computation engine allows us to run large scale data analysis from the R shell.

Also see [SparkR (R on Spark)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html).

To get started you need to set up a Spark cluster. This [web page](http://paxcel.net/blog/how-to-setup-apache-spark-standalone-cluster-on-multiple-machine/) should help.  The Spark documentation, without using Mesos or YARN as your cluster manager, is [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html). Once you have Spark set up, see Wendy Yu's [tutorial](https://rpubs.com/wendyu/sparkr) on SparkR. She also shows how to integrate H20 with Spark which is referred to as 'Sparkling Water'.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian. I have several window servers (local network). Do you know any document/guidance with examples that can help me how to write the codes using SparkR to distribute the computing to servers? Thanks again!!

Comment: I updated my answer with more instructions.

Answer (score 2):

For several releases now, R has been shipping with a base library `parallel`.  You could do much worse than starting to read its rather excellent (and still short) [pdf vignette](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf).

In a nutshell, you can just do something like

```
mclapply(1:nCores, someFunction())
```

and the function `someFunction()` will be run in parallel over `nCores`.  A default value of half your physical cores may be a good start.

The [Task View on High-Performance Computing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) has many more pointers.